# What filesystems does iOS use?

Tags: iphone, ios, filesystem, hfs+, apfs

I can't find this information documented anywhere.

What filesystems do iOS devices use?

Did Apple stick with HFS+?

Is it different between devices and iOS versions?

Comment: [In the disk of an iPhone, are *both* HFSX slices journaled?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/108166/8546)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of iOS 10.3 (March 2017) - [APFS/Apple File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) is now the file system being used.

Previous to iOS 10.3 [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) was being used.

APFS will add improved support for solid-state drives and encryption improvements - things that were not a priority 20 years ago when HFS+ was introduced.

Comment: APFS is used by the first developer beta version of iOS 10.3; it *may* be used in the general release of iOS 10.3, but we don't know that yet.

Answer (score 19):

The other answer seems to be correct about the file system being HFSX*, but on being case-*insensitive* (other answer since edited to correct), I found that not to be the case in the book [Mac OS X and iOS Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057651). On page 23 it says:

> In iOS, being **the case sensitive HFSX** by default, case is not only
> preserved, but allows for multiple files to have the same name, albeit
> with a different case. Naturally, case sensitivity means typos produce
> a totally different command or file reference, often a wrong one.
> *[emphasis above is mine]*

Since that didn't agree with the other answer, I sought confirmation.  I loaded a sample iOS project I was working on and changed the name of the database to only differ by case.  After running the app on my iPad mini (iOS 6.1) to re-create the database, I went into iTunes and looked at the files under File Sharing for the application.  Here's what I saw:

[image: Screen shot from iTunes File Sharing demonstrating two file names with identical names differing only by case]

So, it would appear *Mac OS X and iOS Internals* is correct: case is preserved and allows for multiple files to have the same name.

Interestingly, when I selected both files in iTunes' File Sharing and clicked "Save to..." my desktop, I did *not* get any warning.  iTunes apparently "saved" both files to my desktop, but only the initial-uppercase version survived (presumably overwriting the initial-lowercase version of the file.)

---

## * 2017 Update to Apple File System (APFS):

As of **iOS 10.3**, released on March 27, 2017, iOS now uses the new **[Apple File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System)** (APFS), said to be *"optimized for flash and solid-state drive storage, with a primary focus on encryption."*

APFS was announced at WWDC 2016 and there is a WWDC video titled [Introducing Apple File System](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/701/), and an [Apple File System Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for developers. The [features](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Features/Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH5-DontLinkElementID_17) section of the guide may be of specific interest.

Comment: My error I misread the quote and missed the "in"

Comment: @Mark No problem. What's more interesting is the behaviour where it preserves both versions .. something I wouldn't have ended up reading about & testing if not for your innocent error :-)

Answer (score 3):

iOS indeed uses HFSX (HFS+ , case sensitive). You can also use the `HFSleuth` tool from the [Mac OS X/iOS Internals website](http://www.newosxbook.com/index.php), to prove this, and delve deeper into the filesystem structures.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any definitve Apple documents but books quoted in these Stack Overflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735885/what-is-the-file-system-on-iphone) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805623/ios-filesystem-hfs) and this [book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781597496605/chapter-3-file-system-and-data-storage/how_data_is_stored#X2ludGVybmFsX0J2ZGVwRmxhc2hSZWFkZXI/eG1saWQ9OTc4MTU5NzQ5NjYwNS84OA==) say HFSX (ie case sensitive HFS+) which is not the same as the default for OSX.