# In the disk of an iPhone, are both HFSX slices journaled?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, hfs+

## The question

Is journaling enabled for the *system* partition?

### Background

Answers to three questions show that both HFS slices of the disk are HFSX:

- [What is the file system on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7735885) (2011-10-12)
- [What filesystem does iOS use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/83671/8546) (2013-02-27)
- [What file systems does Apple use in iPhones?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107886/8546) (2013-11-01).

[At least one of the two HFSX slices is journaled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107886/what-file-systems-does-apple-use-in-iphones#comment126534_107887).

[Table 3.4](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781597496605/iphone_disk_partitions) of [iPhone and iOS Forensics](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781597496605) shows that journaling is enabled for the *user* data partition.

As Apple sometimes distinguishes between

- JHFS+X (journaled, case sensitive)
- HFSX

– so we **can't assume that HFSX is always journaled**.

#### Types of HFS Plus

iOS and iPhone aside for a moment … Apple's [hdiutil(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) lists four HFS filesystem types for creation purposes:

- HFS+
- HFS+J (JHFS+)
- HFSX
- JHFS+X

The less commonly used expression JHFSX is probably an informal abbreviation of JHFS+X.

Comment: I'll check and let you know what I find.

Comment: I just have to know... why do you care? Why do you want to know? If its just curiosity, cool. But if there's some deep reason and you're planning something... then what? plz tell us!

Comment: @chillin curiosity. "… if Macs begin to use something other than HFS Plus by default, I don't expect iOS to make the same transition at the same time. …" – http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1804066